# Close Docker expose port from parent file

Tags: docker

I have made my own Dockerfile for a apache server that starts with an standard parent file. See first line in my Dockerfile below:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
EXPOSE 8080
```

This parent exposes port 80. Now have I exposed port 8080 in my Dockerfile. Only when I run it both ports are exposed.

It it posible to close the parent port 80 in my Dockerfile? As I cannot edit that file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apart from telling docker to expose the port, you must configure apache to listen 8080, doing these two editions:

1. /etc/apache2/ports.conf
2. /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN sed -si 's/Listen 80/Listen 8080/' /etc/apache2/ports.conf
RUN sed -si 's/VirtualHost .:80/VirtualHost *:8080/' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 8080
```

Then:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image_name
```

Edit:

About port 80. The port is not opened and it's not exposed if you use the previous command. If you don't see the `->80` symbol in `docker ps`, the port is not exposed:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
100fbb367226        php7                       "docker-php-entryp..."   2 minutes ago       Up 46 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   musing_snyder
```

And:

```
▶ docker inspect 100fbb367226 -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Ports}}"
{"80/tcp":null,"8080/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"8080"}]}
```

Comment: Yes I did this and port 8080 is working. Only port 80 is also exposed from the parent Dockerfile. I would like to have port 80 closed?

Comment: But bear in mind that the port 80 is exposed but it is not opened.

Comment: That is true, so maybe no problem to leave it open as there is noting behind it.

Comment: I couldn't find how to un-expose a port. It was a discussion before: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8709

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **this is currently impossible**.

But you can [follow this issue on Docker's GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465). It's from 2014, but it is still *Open*. Never know...

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, rather than editing the configuration in the docker image you can also use port mapping to achieve the same result.

For example mapping port 8080 on the host to port 80 within the docker image, like so:

`docker run -d -p 8080:80 image_name`

Comment: That is true, but I use Docker-compose and it will be internal port number for multiple apache containers. In this way it is exposed outside the host.

Comment: @Tom docker-compose can also set the `ports: 'host-port:container-port'` for each server.  Each apache container can use 80 internally and a different port publicly.